# Removing documents from a mongo collection with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am building a web-based inventory system and am trying to implement a delete function in the case that an item is entered in error. All of the examples I've looked at look very simple but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<?php
   // Start the session
   session_start();

   $id = $_SESSION['id'];

   $mongo = new MongoClient(); // connect

   $db = $mongo->test; // set db

   $collection = $db->check_out; // set collection

   $collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), true);

   header('Location: main.php');
?>
```

I have printed out $id and seen that it does match the value stored in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

`$collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), array("justOne" => true));`

`justOne` - is the field to say how many element you have to delete

Comment: I printed out $id using echo and it matches the value stored in my database.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try that.

Comment: Thanks! That worked out great! I really wish the PHP docs would've made that a little clearer.